# How do I create a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, class

This is what I got so far, and it's not working at all :( all the variables are null in my player class and update never gets called.

I mean a programming class, not a css class. I.E. not (.movingdiv{color: #ff0000;})

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Class Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body { text-align: center; background-color: #ffffff;}
            #box { position: absolute; left: 610px; top: 80px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.onkeydown=function(event){keyDown(event)};
            document.onkeyup=function(event){keyUp(event)};
            var box = 0;

            function Player () {
                var speed = 5;
                var x = 50;
                var y = 50;
            }

            function update() {
                box.style.left = this.x + "px";
                box.style.top = this.y + "px";
                box.innerHTML = "<h6 style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">X: "+ this.x + "<br /> Y: " + this.y + "</h6>";
            }

            var player = new Player();
            var keys = new Array(256);
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0;i <= 256; i++){
                keys[i] = false;
            }

            function keyDown(event){
               keys[event.keyCode] = true;
            }

            function keyUp(event){
               keys[event.keyCode] = false; 
            }

            function update(){
                if(keys[37]) player.x -= player.speed;
                if(keys[39]) player.x += player.speed;

                player.update();
            }

            setInterval(update, 1000/60);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box" ></div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            box = document.getElementById('box');
            box.innerHTML = "<h6 style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\">X: "+ player.x + "<br /> Y: " + player.y + "</h6>";
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Edit: alright, I think I messed up here. The first time I tried to make a class I seem to have messed up. After retrying I seem to be able to now using the "1 Using a function" in Meders post.

the real problem seems to be that javascript doesn't know what to do when it gets to this line in my real code:

```
box.style.background-position = "" + -(this.frame * this.width) + "px " + -(this.state * this.height) + "px";
```

It also seems to choke anytime I put

`box.style.background-color`

So the question I need answered now is how do I set a value to style variables in javascript that have a "-" in the name. I'll post a test in a second

Comment: What doesn't work? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: all the variables are null in my player class and update never gets called.

Comment: Which `update`? I see two functions named `update`. And you're calling `player.update`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: If you have an entirely new question, please make a new question and leave this question as is.

Comment: Regarding the CSS property `background-color`: you should camelCase them, like `box.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: Alright. thank you all for helping me. I gave Jan Kuboschek the answer because he answered the titled question. But I did upvote Marcel's comment, and Mader's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) article, there are three ways to define a class in JavaScript:

**1 Using a function**

Example:

```
 function Apple (type) {
     this.type = type;
     this.color = "red";
     this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
 }

 function getAppleInfo() {
     return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
 }


 var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
 apple.color = "reddish";
 alert(apple.getInfo());
```

**2 Using JSON**

```
 var apple = {
     type: "macintosh",
     color: "red",
     getInfo: function () {
         return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
     }
 }


 apple.color = "reddish";
 alert(apple.getInfo());
```

**3 Singleton using a function**

```
 var apple = new function() {
     this.type = "macintosh";
     this.color = "red";
     this.getInfo = function () {
         return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
     };
 }


 apple.color = "reddish";
 alert(apple.getInfo());
```

Comment: Yeah, I seen this article, but when I tried using the 3nd style it didn't work at all. That's the one I need to use cause the 2rd is a per variable class.

Comment: what variables are you talking about? be more specific. you are being way too vague.

Comment: @William please clarify - you want to use the 3rd or the 2nd? :)

Comment: Your second example is not JSON. There is no such thing as a function in JSON.

Answer (score 6):

The `var` makes a private variable, do prefix with `this` instead in your constructor:

```
        function Player () {
            this.speed = 5;
            this.x = 50;
            this.y = 50;
            var pri = 'private';
            this.update = function() {
                  if(keys[37]) this.x -= this.speed;
                  if(keys[39]) this.x += this.speed;
            }
        }

        var player = new Player;
        alert( player.speed ) // should alert 5
        alert( player.pri ) // should fail or say undefined
```

You can also do...

```
      var player = {
           speed: 5,
           x:50,
           y:50,
           update: function() {
               // code
           }
      }
```

And then get rid of `new Player` and the `Player` constructor.

Comment: "The var makes a private variable" - you mean local?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Player like a constructor, but it is not set up like one.

Rather than using `var` inside the constructor function, like `var speed = 5;`
you need to use

```
this.speed=5;
```

Then it wil return an instance of Player. As it is, you're just setting some variables and returning nothing in particular.

Now, as far as learning JS object creation and inheritance, I suggest checking out Douglas Crockford's resources.  As you may know, it's not intended to be class-based like Java, PHP, Python and so on. JavaScript has prototypal inheritance based on cloning objects that already exist.

Crockford discusses doing class-based inheritance in JS in [this older article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html). The problem is, you're not using JS to it's best trying to do that. [This treatise](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) may be interesting where he explains one way of cloning objects. That is the Object.beget method, which is good, but has limits as well. The best way is the 'functional' method. Sorry for the PowerPoint links, but you should read this: http://www.crockford.com/codecamp/The%20Good%20Parts%20ppt/4%20prototypal.ppt and this: http://www.crockford.com/codecamp/The%20Good%20Parts%20ppt/5%20functional.ppt

http://video.yahoo.com/watch/630959/2974197 is one version of a video where Crockford discusses the ins and outs of JS.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook is another of the same.

I really recommend getting the book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) for a thorough run down of pragmatic advanced JavaScript.

Comment: To add to that: [JavaScript. The Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596101996/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) is perhaps better suited for someone who doesn't know JavaScript's OOP already.

Comment: That book is quite good and thorough, also. The difference is that it covers the DOM and browsers thoroughly, while The Good Parts is strictly about the language itself.