# How do I create a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a student class in javascript with 2 data members Name and Age and 2 method get_record() and set_record(name,age). How do I do it in javascript and create multiple object of that class.

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034274/how-do-i-create-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: Did you [look around on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+create+class)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Student  = function(age, name){
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;

  this.get_age = function(){
      return this.age;
  }
  this.get_name = function(){
      return this.name;
  }
  this.set_age = function(age){
      this.age = age;
  }
  this.set_name = function(name){
      this.name = name;
  }
}

var student = new Student(20,"XYZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can model classes with new JavaScript based languages. [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/) and [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) are probably the most popular in this respect.

This example is based on the JavaScript output from a TypeScript class.

```
    var Student = (function() {
        function Student(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        Student.prototype.get_record = function() {
            return "Name: " + this.name + "\nAge: " + this.age;
        }

        Student.prototype.set_record = function(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        return Student;
    })();

// Usage

var a = new Student("John", 23);
var b = new Student("Joe", 12);
var c = new Student("Joan", 44);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function student (age,name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.get_record = function() {
              return "name:"+this.name+" , age:"+this.age;
        }
        this.set_record = function(_name,_age) {
             this.name=_name;
             this.age=_age;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'constructor function'.

```
function Student() {
    this.get_record = function(){ return this.name; };
    this.set_record = function(name, age) { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.age = age; 
    };

    return this;
}

var student1 = new Student();
var student2 = new Student();

student1.set_record('Mike', 30);
student2.set_record('Jane', 30);

student1.get_record();
student2.get_record();
```

More complex class structures are constructed via prototypes